# Arrow keys navigation within a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Arrow key (left and right) is not navigating within a text field. Also placing a cursor within a text field and editing is not possible. Cursor jumps to the last every time I start adding a character. It works fine in firefox but not working in Chrome and IE. Code is as below.

```
$('#idname').bind('keyup blur', function(){ 
  $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z A-Z 0-9]/g,'') ); 
});
```

Am using jquery version 1.3.

Comment: Remove the `keyup` and just keep `blur`. Modifying the value as the user types is annoying even when it works...

Comment: When i remove keyup, arrow key is working, but the regular expression validation is not happening.It is accepting all characters irrespective of the condition

Comment: My point was to only validate when the user leaves the field (on blur).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the parameter in val() width a function like in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/robbiebardijn/Z4p48/

```
    $(this).val( function(){ 
      $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z A-Z 0-9]/g,'')
    });
```

That function also accepts 2 parameters and you should return your altered value.

this comes from the doc:

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).val(function( i, val ) {
    return val.toUpperCase();
  });
});
```

Comment: The suggestion to pass a function to `.val()` won't work unless the function actually returns the new value. Also it's pointless if the function body uses `$(this).val()` - might as well stick with what the OP had if you're going to do that. Maybe you meant to recommend this: `$(this).val(function(i,oldVal) { return oldVal.replace(...); });`?

Comment: Yeah i know, it was just to emphasize the use of a function parameter, it must have a return value. Why should this not work? It comes straight of the doc. So you must have something else wrong

Comment: @RobbieBardijn - am new to jquery/js..could u please elloborate on ur point.

Comment: What exactly is your goal?

Comment: the code i gave is validating a text field.The problem is , i could not edit or move in the text field using left or right arrow key.whenever i place a cursor in the text field and try to insert a character ,the cursor jumps to the end of the text.This problem is only in chrome and IE.It works in mozilla.

Comment: the code i gave is validating a text field.The problem is , i could not edit or move in the text field using left or right arrow key.whenever i place a cursor in the text field and try to insert a character ,the cursor jumps to the end of the text.This problem is only in chrome and IE.It works in mozilla